# Kubernetes: Role vs ClusterRole

Tags: kubernetes

Which is the difference between a `Role` or a `ClusterRole`?

When should I create one or the other one?

I don't quite figure out which is the difference between them.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/):

> A Role can only be used to grant access to resources within a single namespace.

Example: List all pods in a namespace

> A ClusterRole can be used to grant the same permissions as a Role, but
>   because they are cluster-scoped, they can also be used to grant access
>   to:
>
> ```
> cluster-scoped resources (like nodes)
> non-resource endpoints (like “/healthz”)
> namespaced resources (like pods) across all namespaces (needed to run kubectl get pods --all-namespaces, for example)
> ```

Examples: List all pods in all namespaces. Get a list of all nodes and theis public IP.

Comment: So if I need a single ServiceAccount with access to a defined set of NameSpaces, I guess binding it to a number of Roles (one for each namespace) is the right way? What if the exact NS names (e.g. all namespaces that match "projectx-*" ) are not known ahead of time?

Answer (score 1):

Cluster roles also allow for the reuse of common permission sets across namespaces (via role bindings).  The bootstrap admin, edit and view cluster roles are the canonical examples.