# Can a Kubernetes Role be granted to access cluster scoped resources such as CRD and ClusterRole?

Tags: kubernetes

Refering to this question [Kubernetes: Role vs ClusterRole](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51647643/kubernetes-role-vs-clusterrole). I understand that `A Role can only be used to grant access to resources within a single namespace.` so it should not be able to access to cluster scoped resources like `customresourcedefinitions` or `clusterroles`. I've created a Role and granted all resources to it like this.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: myaccount
  namespace: test
---
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: testadmin
  namespace: test
rules:
  - apiGroups: ['*']
    resources: ['*']
    verbs: ['*']
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: testadminbinding
  namespace: test
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: myaccount
    namespace: test
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: testadmin
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Then I tried this but it got 'yes' (with warning).

```
$ kubectl auth can-i create customresourcedefinitions --as=system:serviceaccount:test:myaccount
Warning: resource 'customresourcedefinitions' is not namespace scoped in group 'apiextensions.k8s.io'
yes
```

Also 'yes' with `clusterroles` and `clusterrolebindings` which are cluster scoped.

I'm a little bit confuse if a Role can really access cluster scoped resources? Can anyone help explain this behavior please?

Comment: Sounds wrong. Are you sure RBAC is enabled in this cluster? Are you sure there isn't some other RBAC granting additional provileges to "system:serviceaccount:test:myaccount". Is it normal "myaccount" doesn't match SA name in your yaml sample?

Comment: What is the output if you do `kubectl auth can-i create persistentvolumes --as=system:serviceaccount:test:myaccount`?

Comment: @SYN Yes it is enabled. It is a newly created cluster and I only add SA myaccount and the Role to it.

Comment: @gohm'c It got `Warning: resource 'persistentvolumes' is not namespace scoped
no`

Comment: When using `can-i` to test a cluster-scoped resource, be sure to use the `-A` argument, otherwise the results are invalid (and you receive a warning).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are absolutely right, a Role is used to grant access to resources within a namespace, but I should clarify a few things:

1. `customresourcedefinitions` can be either namespaced or cluster-scoped, and are available to all namespaces, that is why it is returning as `yes` when testing, according to the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/extend-kubernetes/custom-resources/custom-resource-definitions/):

> When you create a new CustomResourceDefinition (CRD), the Kubernetes
> API Server creates a new RESTful resource path for each version you
> specify. The CRD can be either namespaced or cluster-scoped, as
> specified in the CRD's scope field. As with existing built-in `objects, deleting a namespace deletes all custom objects in that namespace. CustomResourceDefinitions themselves are non-namespaced and are available to all namespaces.`

2. `clusterroles` and `clusterrolebindings` are NOT resources, clusterroles are just a set of permissions that can be assigned to resources within a given cluster, and a clusterrolebinding is the way to grant those permissions cluster-wide.

To properly  test the created Role and RoleBinding, you can do it with a resource like a Pod:

You should be able to create a pod within the namespace "test" with the service account "myaccount", but not with any other user.

```
kubectl auth can-i create pod --as=system:serviceaccount:test:myaccount --namespace=test
yes
kubectl auth can-i create pod --as=system:serviceaccount:test:otheraccount --namespace=test
no
```

And you should not be able to create the same resource at any namespace other than "test" with either user.

```
kubectl auth can-i create pod --as=system:serviceaccount:test:myaccount
no
kubectl auth can-i create pod --as=system:serviceaccount:test:otheraccount
no
```

Comment: This answer has some mischaracterizations and invalid conclusions, please disregard. The OP is using `can-i` incorrectly, and the answer doesn't really speak to the question of how a RoleBinding combines with a ClusterRole that grants access to cluster-scoped resources.

Comment: I think is is incorrect, there is no such thing as resources of the same type being both cluster and namespaced-scoped. For instance, CRDs are always cluster-scoped.